# When I say 'She teaches high school English', do I use H and S as capital? (American English)

Tags: capitalization

When I say 'She teaches high school English', do I use H and S as capital?  (American English)

Comment: If you think there's such a thing as "High School English" (as opposed to simply saying [*She teaches English at high school*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22teaches+english+at+high+school%22)) then you should probably capitalize it to reflect that. But personally, I think only non-native speakers would think like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe a British/American difference.  ["She teaches high school English"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=QXttXM7ZJo6jjwS-nKnYAw&q=%22teaches+high+school+English%22&oq=%22teaches+high+school+English%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...52184.57021.0.57285.20.17.0.0.0.0.280.2118.0j10j3.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..12.0.0....0.Cs-hDveCtQg) is fairly common here.

Comment: @Juhasz: I'm quite sure of that. At the moment there are probably far more US teenagers than UK equivalents who don't actually know English very well, so they still need to be taught *normal / correct use of the language itself* at high school (as opposed to studying English Literature, dabbling in linguistics, etc.). But to a first approximation many of those teenagers are in fact "non-native speakers".

Answer (score 3):

**No you do not.** At least not in general.

If what you mean is that she teaches English at high school, then neither 'high school English' nor 'high school' are themselves proper nouns and so are not capitalized. "She teaches high school English." is correct. This is going to be 99% of cases.

You might use capitals if she teaches a specific course, whose formal title is "High School English".

Under more bizarre circumstances you might capitalize if she taught English at a specific school called High School (presumably in the little-known town of 'High').

Answer (score 0):

If a particular place is identified in the sentence, it would be a proper noun, and therefore capitalized.

Ex. She teaches English at ABC High School.

But absent that, "high school" is a common noun and should not be capitalized.